# SUMIFS part of a string and exclude the rest

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to get this formula to ignore the times on the data in column D and look up the date to calculate the costs per day, but can't seem to get this working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are apparently trying to sum B:B from B2; that seems like a circular reference. I believe you are trying to sum E:E.

```
=sumifs(E:E, D:D, ">="&A2, D:D, "<"&A2+1)
```

Comment: I'm clearly a total idiot. This works perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: We're all a bit thick at one time or another. I once copied something to the clipboard at one workstation then wheeled my steno chair to another workstation and tried to paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in B2 then drag down:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,"<=" & A2 + 1 - TIMEVALUE("00:00:01"),D:D,">=" & A2)
```

It works by searching on less than or equal to the last second of the date in A2 (add 1 day then minus 1 second) and greater than or equal to the first second on the date in A2.

Edit: Damn I over complicated that, user11087823 has put a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` as shown below:

[image]

I suggest you read about how dates and times are stored in Excel, as you will note that I used mathematics, and not string functions, to remove the time portion.